# Node-RED communication using CA certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, nodes, node-red

i am trying to deploy my node-RED environment using CA certificate.
i have created the pem files using .p12 file by executing below commands

```
– openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -passin pass:Password -out keyfile.pem -nodes
– openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -passin pass:Password -out crtfile.pem -nodes
```

then i have uncommented the https code from settings.js file of node red

```
 https: {
        key: require("fs").readFileSync('keyfile.pem'),
        cert: require("fs").readFileSync('crtfile.pem')
    }
```

i have used default http node and made the following configuration to the tls config
[image]

when i deploy the node i get the following error

```
"Error: unable to verify the first certificate"
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: You've not filled in the path to the CA cert in the http node TLS config

Comment: @hardillb  am not exactly sure what file needs to placed here. is it the .p12 file converted to pem format or the .cer file converted to pem format, can you please help

Comment: It's also not clear what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to setup Node-RED to be served over HTTPS or trying to access a remote site using TLS Client Certificates for authentication. These are 2 very different tasks.

Comment: i am trying to access a remote site using TLS Client Certificates for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the changes you made to the `settings.js`. That section is only for if you want to have Node-RED serve the editor via TLS.

Next your openssl commands to export the user'sprivate key and certificate should probably be more like

```
openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -out keyfile.pem -passin pass:Password -nocerts
openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -out crtfile.crt -passin pass:Password -nokeys -clcert
```

You should also export the include CA chain with

```
openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -out ca.crt -passin pass:Password -cacerts -nokeys
```

You then need to add the `ca.crt` file to the HTTP node's TLS config.

Comment: should i be converting crtfile.crt and ca.crt files to .pem files because in the http request node it says pem format.

Comment: "openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -out ca.crt -passin pass:Password -cacerts -nokeys"

when i try doing this i get ca.crt file of 0 bytes.

Comment: The files are already in pem format. If your p12 file doesn't contain any ca certs (as implied by getting a zero length file) then make sure you uncheck the "Verify server certificate" box and leave the ca file box empty

Comment: what is the trust store of node-red from which validates the CA certificates?
is it OS trust store or mozilla firefox trust store?

Comment: The NodeJS binary has it's own baked in truststrore

Comment: just one final question...if i uncheck verify ca certificate, is my system susceptible for data breach, like Man in the middle attack.

Comment: potentially, which is why you should supply a suitable CA file to put in the config if the servers certificate is not signed by a public CA